# Google Places API request Call

Tags: android, api

i've been struggeling with this all day now

I want to make an API call to Google Places but i can't seem to figure it out.
I've tried this: http://blog.brianbuikema.com/2010/08/android-development-part-1-using-googles-places-api-to-develop-compelling-location-based-mobile-applications/

And now I have a string like this:

```
http://maps.google.com/maps/api/place/search/xml?location=40.717859,-73.9577937&radius=1600&client=clientId&sensor=true_or_false&signature=SIGNATURE
```

Where I have the clientID as my client ID for the Places API on my gmail account and the signature filled by the UrlSinger's method `signRequest`

Now how do I get an XML or JSON object back?
Do I need to make a `HttpRequest` or a `HttpPost` (Or something completely different) ? I'm totally new to that.
I would love some example code.

Thanks in advance,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After another day of struggeling, I face-palmed myself.

Solution: Why would I need that signature?

A link like this works just fine:

```
https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/search/json?location=50.936364,5.873566&radius=500&name=ziekenhuis&sensor=false&key=FILL_IN_KEY_HERE
```

Retreiving the JSON object is being done by this method

```
private JSONObject executeHttpGet(String uri) throws Exception{
    HttpGet req = new HttpGet(uri);

    HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
    HttpResponse resLogin = client.execute(req);
    BufferedReader r = new BufferedReader(
            new InputStreamReader(resLogin.getEntity()
                    .getContent()));
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    String s = null;
    while ((s = r.readLine()) != null) {
        sb.append(s);
}
```

Which I found here (At the bottom of the post):

```
http://blog.simonstahl.com/2011/03/16/login-with-oauth-to-the-foursquare-api-v2-from-android/
```

The method obviously needs some rewriting but it works.